# phonegap background plugin usage

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

In order to run a phonegap app we need plugins , i've installed this plugin 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
followed the steps given
added the following code, but no success. a little help would be appreciated. or are there any plugins about any tutorials are available ?? thanks

```
window.onunload=function(){
           alert("sdcvbh");

          window.plugin.backgroundMode.enable();

   };


onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    alert("v");
    window.plugin.backgroundMode.disable();
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<script src="cordova.js></script>
<script>
    function onDeviceReady(){
        document.addEventListener('pause', onPause, false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume, false);

        window.plugin.backgroundMode.disable();
    }
    function onResume(){
        window.plugin.backgroundMode.disable();
    }
    function onPause(){
        window.plugin.backgroundMode.enable();
    }
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

</script>
```

This will use the cordova deviceready, pause and resume events and should accomplish what you need.

For more info on available events checkout [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events) (current version of cordova is 3.5.0 at the time of writing this.)

Comment: tried it, but unfortunately no success, when i check settings->app->running app , i don't see my app. is any other way to debug that whether the function are being called or not?

Comment: Are you building for iOS or Android? and are you using an emulator or a physical device?

Comment: for both platforms, for now i'm testing it on a android emulator.

Comment: if you are using the android emulator then in your SDK/tools folder there should be a monitor.bat script you can run that will launch the DDMS. There you can watch the log of the device. And you can use `console.log()` to log events. Are you sure you added your plugins correctly? and that you are using the latest version of cordova?